# What pitches are marching band bass drums tuned to?

Tags: drums

What pitch are tuned bass drums? Obviously it can vary, but I'm just looking for a ball-park range. For example, there's two pictures of marching band bass drums on the [wikipedia bass drum page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_drum): what pitch are they likely to have?  Are there particular styles of music where the bass drum(s) is/are tuned outside that pitch range?

Answer (score 4):

When mixing hard rock music the low frequency component of the bass drum usually comes in somewhere between 30Hz and 50Hz, but it's usually not tuned to any specific frequency.

Answer (score 2):

Necro-ing this post, but when I taught, we wouldn't necessarily target specific pitches unless the entirety of the show was in one key, then we'd stay within that key.  Otherwise, we'd aim for perfect fourths between the bottom three drums, then a major third, then a minor third for the top two.  The ranges you can get depend on the size and quality of the drums themselves.